# excel vlookup with if functionc

Tags: excel

For example:

```
F2 = VLOOKUP($L$2,sheet2!$A$2:$G$169,6,0)
```

I would like to add in the function that if $L$2 can not be found in the sheet2!$A$2:$G$169, then show "invalid".

May i know how should i modified to code in excel? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First test what gets returned if $L$2 cannot be found by putting in a value you know is not in the search set. For example if it returns 0 then:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($L$2,sheet2!$A$2:$G$169,6,0) = 0, "invalid", VLOOKUP($L$2,sheet2!$A$2:$G$169,6,0))
```

If it returns an error then try something along the lines of

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($L$2,sheet2!$A$2:$G$169,6,0)), "invalid", VLOOKUP($L$2,sheet2!$A$2:$G$169,6,0))
```

or just

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($L$2,sheet2!$A$2:$G$169,6,0), "invlaid")
```

Comment: Second solution is what everyone uses at work (including myself)